# Wordpress - Woocommerce plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm actually developping an ERP for a client and i'm quite a neophyte with the development on wordpress. I separated all in different classes to add new tabs and panels for the selection of the product type and right now I try to add those informations to the database with the meta data, I want to serialize the informations of the product that I want to add then serialize the informations of the product and the informations of the tab that I created.

Here's my code :

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Rockerz
 * Date: 15/06/17
 * Time: 21:18
 */
class WC_Product_Rental_Schedule_Tab_view {

public static function Inithook_schedule(){
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_data_panels', 
['WC_Product_Rental_Schedule_Tab_view','Render_Schedule'] );
}

/**
 * XXX Rename it Render_Product_Tab_Form
 * Custom Tab Panels informations
 */
public static function Render_Schedule(){

        global $post;
        ?><div id='product_dyu' class='panel woocommerce_options_panel'>
        <div class='options_group'>
            <?php
            woocommerce_wp_text_input(
                array(
                    'id'            => 'date_in',
                    'label'         => __( 'Date in', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'desc_tip'      => 'true',
                    'description'   => __( 'Date in', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'          => 'date',
                )
            );
            woocommerce_wp_text_input(
                array(
                    'id'            => 'date_out',
                    'label'         => __( 'Date out', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'desc_tip'      => 'true',
                    'description'   => __( 'Date out', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'type'          => 'date',
                )
            );
            woocommerce_wp_select( array(
                    'id' => 'status',
                    'name' => 'status[]',
                    'class' => 'status',
                    'label' => __('Status', 'woocommerce'),
                    'options' => array(
                        '1' => 'Pending',
                        '2' => 'In-Stock',
                        '3' => 'Rent',
                        '4' => 'deprecated',
                        '5' => 'Sold',
                    ))
            );
            $users = get_users(array('fields'=>array('ID', 'user_nicename')));
            $selectUser = array(
                'id' => 'users',
                'name' => 'users[]',
                'class' => 'users',
                'label' => __('Users', 'woocommerce'),
            );

            foreach($users as $user){
                $selectUser['options'][$user->ID] = $user->user_nicename;
            }
            woocommerce_wp_select($selectUser);


            ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

this is the informations of the panel that I want to add to the database.
I don't know how to add those infos to the database with the meta, all I know is that I have to serialize all this before adding it to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You probably will not need to serialize anything yourself. WordPress abstracts that away with its APIs. Look into [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta). For adding the meta data to the posts (woocommerce products are a custom post type.)

So when do you use it?

You can hook it to the `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook that is fired when a product is saved. I'm not sure why you are using a static function for your init but I'm going to assume you know. That said add the hook.

You can then use the function you are hooking on to check the `$_POST` variable for the ids of your inputs. That would look something like this:

```
//This goes in you init or constructor
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', array( __CLASS__, 'save_fields' ), 1, 2 );

//This processes and saves data in post_meta
function save_fields( $post_id, $product ) {
        $status = $_POST['status'];
    if ( ! empty( $status ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '{META_KEY_NAME}', esc_attr( $status ) );
    }

}
```

Extra tip:

Besides my answer I see you're using PhpStorm. One of the most valuable tools I used when learning my way around Woocommerce was PhpStorm's "go to definition" feature. The official docs are just autogenerated from the DocBlocks and leave a lot to be desired. I found it invaluable to read through and jump around the code.